# Login route looks for /:id middleware in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, middleware, express-session

I have a middleware function for my post route /blog that prevents users not logged in to add blogs to the site, below is the function:

```
app.use('/blog',(req,res,next) => {
  if ( req.path == '/blog/login') next();
  if (!req.session.user){
    res.status(403)
    res.send('Please login to add blog')
    return
  }
  else{
    next()
  }
})
```

I have a login route that looks like this:

```
router.post('/blog/login', async (req, res) => {

  let { username,password } = req.body;
try{
  checkString(username);
  checkString(password);
  username = username.toLowerCase();
  if (!username.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g)) throw 'Only alphanumeric characters allowed for username'
  if(!password.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g)) throw 'Only alphanumeric and special characters allowed for password'
  if (username.length<4) throw 'Username should have 4 characters or more';
  if (password.length<6) throw 'Password should have 6 characters or more';
  
const ans = await userData.checkUser(username,password)

if (ans==1){
 
  const [id,user,name,pass] = await userData.getValues(username);
  req.session.user = { username:user, name:name, password:pass, userId:id };
  res.send({authenticated:true}) 
  }
} catch(e){
res.send(400,{msg:e})
}

});
```

Below is the route that I want to be able to run without going to the middleware:

```
router.get('/blog/:id', async (req, res) => {

  try{
    const blog = await blogData.getOneBlog(req.params.id);
    res.send(blog)
  }
  catch{
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
  
});
```

My index.js:

```
const blogRoutes = require('./blogs');


const constructorMethod = (app) => {
  
  app.use('/blog', blogRoutes);
  
  

  app.use('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(404);
  });
};

module.exports = constructorMethod;
```

The above route goes directly to the middleware because anything I call after the /blog sends it to the middleware but I only want to send the /blog/:id to the middleware.

Comment: From your current code there's nothing relating to the redirects. Could you post a bit more regarding the routes?

Comment: I have made the edits trying to explain this, basically I have a /blog/login route and another route /blog/:id , now I want to run the middleware only for the /blog/:id route but the login route also goes to the middleware since everything after blog/ goes to the middleware.